# Co-occurence of words/sentences in dataframe

Tags: r

I am new to R (doing social science research) and have a content analysis in which I want to look for co-occuring sentences (but each sentence should be interpreted as a single word). 
My dataframe looks like (header = TRUE):

```
cat1    cat2    cat3  
sentence1   NA  NA  
sentence1   NA  sentence3  
sentence1   sentence2   sentence3  
NA  NA  sentence3  
NA  NA  NA
```

I get the frequency of each category with table(unlist(data))
but I am interested in finding the o-ccurence: How often is cat2 mentioned in the same row with cat3 etc.?

I believe i have to change the data so that R processed each sentence as one unit (=one word)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you

With your *edited* data

```
df <- read.table(text="cat1    cat2    cat3  
sentence1    NA  NA  
sentence1    NA  sentence3  
sentence1    sentence2    sentence3
NA  NA  sentence3  
NA  NA  NA", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Solution

```
result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) if(length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) > 1) { 
                            apply(combn(unique(x[!is.na(x)]), 2), 2, function(y) paste(y, collapse=""))
                        } else { 
                            unique(x[!is.na(x)]) 
                        })
answer <- table(Reduce("c", result))
```

Output

```
# sentence1 sentence1sentence2 sentence1sentence3 sentence2sentence3          sentence3 
        # 1                  1                  2                  1                  1
```

Comment: the "sentence" is different for each category/row. I am looking for co-occuring sentences, e.g. how often is sentence1 co-occuring with sentence2 etc. Your solution gives me 0 matches because each row has a difference sentence.

Comment: You're right. Perhaps you could update your minimal reproducible example.